# Is it possible to add more search providers to the Google Search?

Tags: search, google-search

In the Google Now/Search application, when you view the settings, you get a list of all the applications that can be searched.

Is it possible to develop apps that can add more search providers to this? I'd like to be able to search my calendar and contacts too but I can't seem to.

Earlier Android versions had an application called QuickSearch but this seems to have been removed as per the AOSP commits. Does Android now support in-device search or is this idea dead?

Here's a screenshot of my settings page.

[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: Must be somehow possible. When researching for [Android without Google 4: App Replacements](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-4) I've found some corresponding search apps. Amongst others, your [Quick Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.startapp.quicksearchbox), which is still available at *Google Play*.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it is possible for apps to [make themselves available](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4365208) to be searched, each applications needs to be updated to implement [app indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/) in order for them to show up in this list.

I don't think it is possible to add additional providers without the apps themselves being updated to support this.

Comment: I was just writing the same thing. AFAIK Google Now is expanding to "in app" searching but the app dev needs to enable this, like Multi Window on Samsung I guess.